# 301 + Canonical to link subdomain to root domain for search engines?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-301, canonical-link

I'd like to have the search ranking on my root domain to carry through to my blog subdomain. I'm not sure if this makes sense, but I thought perhaps 301 Redirect from mydomain.com/blog to blog.mydomain.com and having a canonical tag linking back to mydomain.com/blog would help.

For example: A user or search engine goes to mydomain.com/blog/my-post, a 301 redirect takes them to blog.mydomain.com/my-post. On that post is the link tag: rel='canonical' href='mydomain.com/blog/post'

Or, a better example would be someone links to blog.mydomain.com/post and that inbound link goodness gets transferred to mydomain.com. I'm not sure if this works in the other direction: i.e. a link to mydomain.com transferring link goodness to blog.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work. The 301 redirect will be followed by search engines to determine the "real" canonical URL.

See the [Google FAQ](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html):

> **Can rel="canonical" be a redirect?**
>
> Yes, you can specify a URL that redirects as a canonical URL. Google will then process the redirect as usual and try to index it.

However, [RFC 6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3) discourages to use a permanent redirect:

> To better ensure that applications properly handle the canonical link relation, administrators ought to consider the following guidelines:
>
> […]
>
> Avoid designating the target (canonical) as:
>
> […]
>
> The source IRI of a permanent redirect (for HTTP, this refers to 300 and 301 response codes defined in Sections 10.3.1 and 10.3.2 of [RFC2616]

Answer (score -1):

What framework/language/CMS are you working with?

I guess you could dynamically add your canonical element

```
<!-- html from mydomain.com -->

%define_domain% = ( %define_domain% ) ? 'mydomain.com' : 'blog.mydomain.com'
%extra_goodness% = 'blog/my-post'


<meta name="canonical" content="%define_domain% / %extra_goodness%">
```

Comment: My question is not how to use the canonical tag but whether the system I outlined above is effective at transferring all link goodness to the same root domain. Again, mydomain.com/blog/post -> 301 redirect -> blog.mydomain.com/post which contains a canonical tag referencing the root domain